# Compare two files and output difference from the first separator

Tags: awk, cmd, git-bash

I will ask my question with an example (fake passwords + fake names/domain). I have two files:

**1.txt (containing new emails with passwords)**

```
gwennette.prutzman93ent@stackprotect.com:fwgzvg
kimbler.ellizabeth@stackprotect.com:ft5tz45
cectvshowtape@stackprotect.com:rfh44f32q
standiford.gyneth5566@stackprotect.com:zh6535
lecroy.jeanlucas5329@stackprotect.com:frb46
```

**2.txt (containing old emails from my database without passwords)**

```
2de0aae2fdfd4025a0236869bb091488@stackprotect.com
standiford.gyneth5566@stackprotect.com
lecroy.jeanlucas5329@stackprotect.com
cectvshowtape@stackprotect.com
fiorillo.alianny@stackprotect.com
gwennette.prutzman93ent@stackprotect.com
kimbler.ellizabeth@stackprotect.com
vincente-gunnard@stackprotect.com
anjum.coetta0376@stackprotect.com
grandison-liboria9587@stackprotect.com
```

I'm expecting to get an output like this:

**3.txt (lines from the 2.txt which are not duplicates from the file 1.txt from the first column/separator)**

```
2de0aae2fdfd4025a0236869bb091488@stackprotect.com
fiorillo.alianny@stackprotect.com
vincente-gunnard@stackprotect.com
anjum.coetta0376@stackprotect.com
grandison-liboria9587@stackprotect.com
```

I'm trying to see which emails didn't went through my 2.txt file (database) so that I can run them again.

I tried a several Regex solutions, but not one could help with my problem.

`findstr /V /I /X /L /G:"2.txt" "1.txt" > "3.txt"`

`findstr /v /g:"2.txt" "1.txt" > 3.txt`

Comment: You shall not have ever published passwords even hashed passwords here at all. Now that it cannot be undone because it is now public forever. It is your responsibility to immediately notify users you leaked their passwords. Depending on your country's legislation, other actions from you may be required by law.

Comment: Hello Lea, these are fake passwords typed randomly on keyboard, and a fake domain + names.

Comment: @s4kkq FYI the domain `example.com` exists for us to use when creating anything fake, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com.

Comment: @s4kkq What Ed Morton said, + make it clear those are fake passwords, for tranquility of readers/reviewers of your post.

Comment: `findstr /V /I /B /L /G:"2.txt" "1.txt" > "3.txt"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' 1.txt 2.txt
2de0aae2fdfd4025a0236869bb091488@stackprotect.com
fiorillo.alianny@stackprotect.com
vincente-gunnard@stackprotect.com
anjum.coetta0376@stackprotect.com
grandison-liboria9587@stackprotect.com
```

That's how you'd do it in Unix, you'll have to figure out the Windows quoting yourself if you want to do it on Windows.

Comment: Hello Ed, Thank you very much for your help. I figured it out with your help. It works fine on Windows via Gitbash.